# A “branching process” for finite groups

Tags: probability, group-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $\{X_{i,j}\}_{i, j \in \mathbb{N}}$ are a set of i.i.d. random elements of $G$. Now suppose that $\{A_i\}_{i = 0}^\infty$ is a sequence of random elements of $G$ defined by the following relations:

$$P(A_0 = e) = 1$$
$$A_{n+1} = \Pi_{i = 1}^{ord{A_{n}}} X_{(n+1), i}$$

Here $\Pi$ stands for iterated group product, and $ord$ for the order of an element.

My question is:

> Is it always true, that $\exists H \leq G$, such that $\forall g \in G$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_{n} = g) = \frac{I_H(g)}{|G|}$?

Here $I_H$ stands for indicator function of $H$.

This statement is true for the following borderline cases:

If $X_{1, 1}$ is uniformly distributed on $G$, then $H$ is equal to $G$. This is because if $A$ and $B$ are two independent uniformly distributed random elements of a finite group, then $AB$ is also uniformly distributed.

If $X_{1, 1}$ is degenerate ($\exists g \in G$, such that $P(X_{1, 1} = g) = 1)$), then $H$ is trivial, as $\forall g \in G$ $g^{ord(g)} = e$ by definition of group element order.

But is that statement true in general?

Comment: can you include the proofs of your borderline cases?

Comment: I don't think the degenerate case is quite right -- e.g. when $G = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $g = 1$, $A_n$ will always alternate between $A_n = 0$ and $A_n = 1$, right?

Comment: @user125932, I think, you have just found a counterexample to my conjecture. Please, post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, there seems to be a counterexample in the degenerate case: when $G = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $g = 1$, we see that $A_n$ alternates so that $A_{2n} = 0$ (with probability $1$) and $A_{2n+1} = 1$ (with probability $1$), meaning no such $H$ exists.